# 'Overriding' class member

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

quick question: I have a base class with a member variable and I'm trying to 'override' this value in a derived class. How do I do this exactly?

I tried:

```
class A
{
public:
    double i = 1;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    double i = 2;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B* b = new B();
    A* a = b;
    std::cout << b->i << '\t' << a->i << std::endl;  // output 2    1
}
```

But the desired output is '2    2'. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Niklas

Comment: Use a virtual function.

Comment: You can override virtual functions, not data members.

Comment: Why not just assign a new value to `i` in the constructor of `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override virtual **functions**; you can't override **data members**. This class hierarchy has two **different** members named `i`, one in class `A` and one in class `B`.

If you want the derived class to change the value of `i` that's in the base class, just do it in the constructor: `B() { i = 2; }`. But a better approach would be to have a constructor for `A` that sets the value of `i`, and to call that from `B`:

```
A::A(int ii = 1) : i(ii) {}
B::B() : A(2) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is even a simplier solution than Pete proposed.

Just define your class B like this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { i = 2; }
}
```

So that class B will reuse the member i defined in its base (A) and its default value will be "overriden" to 2 so your test code will return "2 2".

That's how you 1) don't change the base class A (don't add that unnecessary int argument with a default value, some people even say that function parameters with default values is a bad practice in c++) and 2) don't add an overhead of virtual functions to your classes (which is also unnecessary in your simple code).

Comment: This does not seem possible if I say const double i  in class A. Is there a way around it?

Comment: No, const is a different thing, const can be initialized in constructor (A) only, so in that case you need to use Pete's solution.